# Redirect asp to php with variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have links like:

folder/dataBuy.asp?numOrder=578

that I want redirect to

folder/dataBuy.php?numOrder=578

the numOrder is an autoincrement variable (579, 580 ...)
My server doesn't support asp, so I need a solution using htaccess.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(folder)/([^.]+)\.asp$ /$1/$2.php [L,NC]
```